# Area of a rectangle within a curve

Tags: calculus, integration

The cargo space of a bulk carrier is 60m long.  The shaded part of the diagram represents the uniform cross-section of this space.  It is shaped like a parabola with equation ${{1\over 4}x^2, - 6 \le x \le 6}$ between the lines ${y = 1}$ and ${y = 9}$.  Find the area of the cross section and hence find the volume of cargo that this ship can carry:

[image]

I am not looking for the answer but really some indication of how to start this question.  I think I need to find out the x values first but I don't understand why a range has been given for x or how I use this range.

Comment: You are asked to find the shaded area of the cross section!

Comment: You will need to perform two integrations: one for the complete cross-section (including the unshaded part), and one for the unshaded part. Then the area of the shaded part will be their difference. I must say, I don't like the way that the straight line at the top has been drawn as a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the area in the parabola then subtract the area inside the parabola but bellow $y=1$.

For the area inside the parabola:

> $$ \int_{-6}^{6}\left(9-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)dx $$

For the area inside the parabola but bellow $y=1$:

> $$ \frac{x^2}{4}=1 \implies x=\pm 2, \;\; \text{therefore,} \;\; \int_{-2}^{2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)dx $$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a large rectangle of $12\times 9$ enclosing the shaded cross-section & a small rectangle of $4\times 1$ inside, hence the required area of cross-section $$=12\times 9-4\times 1-2\int_{-2}^0y\ dx$$
$$=104-2\int_{-6}^{-2}\frac{x^2}{4}\ dx$$
$$=104-\frac 12\int_{-6}^{-2}x^2\ dx$$
$$=104-\frac 12\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-6}^{-2}$$
$$=104-\frac{104}{3}=\color{red}{\frac{208}{3}\ \mathrm{m^2}}$$
hence the volume of the cargo
$$=\text{(area of cross-section)}\times (\text{length})$$
$$=\frac{208}{3}\times 60=\color{red}{4160\ \mathrm{m^3}}$$

Comment: I can see where 12 comes from but what about 4 in 4 times 1

Comment: Extend the dotted lines to the x-axis, you will get a small rectangle $4\times 1$ to be subtracted from area of rectangle $12\times 9$

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the shaded part:$$2\bigg(\int_{x=-6}^{x=0}\int_{y=x^2/4}^{y=9}1\text{dydx}\bigg)-2\bigg(\int_{x=-2}^{x=0}\int_{y=x^2/4}^{y=1}1\text{dydx}\bigg)=\frac{208}{3}$$